# Stray puppy wants to eat with its littermates but gets attacked whenever it does

Tags: dogs, psychology, territory

I usually feed milk to newly born stray puppies as soon as I come to know about their existence in my area. However, when the puppies grow enough, they start fighting.

**14 days ago**

Recently, among a litter of puppies, I found that one puppy was being beaten by the other puppies. That puppy became sad and for two days it did not drink milk or anything, so I moved it to a different area with a different bowl. But the problem was it was not eating anything.

**After 3 days**

I took it to the vet hospital and the vet gave it injections and provided a bottle with glucose solution. After the puppy drank from the bottle, it had some energy and started to drink water. For two days I gave it the syrup given by the vet and fed it separately from the other puppies.

**After 4 days**

After 4 days, it started drinking milk, but it still wasn't eating anything. Unfortunately though it also seemed that **it was now strongly interested in making a group** with those other puppies again. It started not drinking milk which was given separately in its personal bowl and started going to the bowl provided for the other puppies.

The other puppies, on seeing it, started barking and attacking it again, and it again became distressed. It again started not eating anything and drinking anything.

Because of the syrup medicine, it was starving strongly, and still not drinking the milk that was in its bowl and instead trying to drink from the other puppys' bowl. So all of them were jumping on it and barking. One of them injured it and injured the area near its ear and eye, drawing blood. This happened in my absence but my friend told me what happened. All the puppies are vaccinated.

I now feel that even though I do any medicines it will not work. The glucose bottle never works. I spent a lot of time with the puppy to make it feel safe - it sleeps on my legs, it plays with me, but when it comes for food, it still goes to the other puppies to be bullied. It feels very sad and hungry but still not eating separately and it is still interested in being bullied.

**What is more important? Letting the puppy bond with the other puppies, or making sure it eats?**

---

**Update:** Today, I saw that the puppy was again attacked by the other puppies and was again forced to leave the territory. I made it its separate area, a safe place nearby. It finally ate food separately today, but now it is scared. It still visits the other puppies when we are away. The other puppies do not bark at it unless it tries to eat from their bowl. So the fight is for the bowl, not for food. Today I put too much food in both the bowls - both bowls were full and the food was mostly wasted.

How can we help this puppy?

Comment: Both are very important and instinctive needs.  Do you need your head or your heart more?

Comment: Do you mean that you found this puppy on the street? Where/how did you get it from?

Comment: @starsplusplus - In India stray animals are accepted and even revered as is all life.  It is very different from the US or Europe

Comment: @Critters Did you assume some kind of implied criticism in my question? I assure you there was none. I'm simply trying to make an edit to improve the English of the post so that people can understand it better. However, it's a bit unclear in places (hence the editing!) so I'm trying to get the relevant details from the OP so that I make sure I get them all in there.

Comment: @starsplusplus - Just clarifing that street dog was basically the same thing as a stray in the US/UK

Comment: Thank you all for your kind response to this question, can some one please guide me to right direction if I am not on right path?

Comment: You could probably ask how to get the puppy to eat. and in another question how to help the puppy integrate better with his pack.

Comment: @Critters okey,.... I am trying to edit it... but please you also put some directions if it is improper... Thank You...

Comment: @ParthTrivedi How/where did the puppy come from?

Comment: @starsplusplus It is not coming from anywhere.. It is local street/stray puppy... It is one of the 6 puppies recently born in our sector...